# Read data into 2 dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to read a data file into a 2 dimensional array.
For example:

`file.dat`:

```
1 2 3 a
4 5 6 b
7 8 9 c
```

I tried something like:

```
file=open("file.dat","r")

var = [[]]
var.append([j for j in i.split()] for i in file)
```

but that didn't work.

I need the data in form of two dimensional array as I need to do operations with each element afterwards, e.g.

```
for k in range(3):
    newval(k) = var[k,1]
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: There really isn't a multi-dimensional array construct in Python. The closest thing is a list which contains references to other lists.

Answer (score 3):

```
file = open("file.dat", "r")          # open file for reading

var = []                              # initialize empty array
for line in file:
  var.append(line.strip().split(' ')) # split each line on the <space>, and turn it into an array
                                      # thus creating an array of arrays.
file.close()                          # close file.
```

Comment: Hi @savanto, I tried that but when I try to print the third elements in rows 2 and 3 (print(var[1:2][2])) I am getting an error:

print(var[1:2][2])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user3578925 You cannot access the 'matrix' across rows like that in Python. `var[1:3]` returns an array of arrays with dimensions 2x4, and then accessing the index 2 with `[2]` gives an out-of-bounds error because there are only indices 0 and 1. Try this instead: `print([var[i][2] for i in range(1,3)])`

Comment: Thanks @savanto! That worked! I am starting to think that Python is not the best option for heavy mathematical computations!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
with open("/path/to/file", 'r') as f:
    lines = [[float(n) for n in line.strip().split(' ')] for line in f]
```

It's really weird people said in the comments there is no one line solution for this. It took me so little testing to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = []
with open("data.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.split():
            line = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
            v.append(line)

print(v)
```