# Read k matrices size nxm from stdin in Python

Tags: python, matrix, stdin

I need to read k matrices size nxm from stdin in Python.
In the first line there must be the number of matrices (k), and then - k descriptions of matrices: in the first line 2 integer numbers for size (n and m) devided by space, then the matrix.

Here's an example:

```
2
2 3
4 5 6
3 1 7
4 4
5 3 4 5
6 5 1 4
3 9 1 4
8 5 4 3
```

Could you please tell me how I can do this?
I could have done this only without considering m (for 1 matrix):

```
n = int(input()) 
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append([int(j) for j in input().split()])
```

I have found some similar questions but stdin is not used (e.g. reading from file is used) or the size of string in matrix is not set.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839928/python-read-data-into-2-dimensional-array

Comment: In this question stdin is not used, it is read from file. I've found some questions where stdin is used but they didn't help because the size of strings in matrix is not set in them.

Answer (score 0):

You are on a right way. try to break it in simple steps. Basically a  n X m  matrix is n rows and each row would have m elements (pretty obvious). what if we have n=1 then we have a line in which there would be m element. to take such input we would just

```
matrix = input().split()  #read the input
matrix = [ int(j) for j in matrix]   #matrix is now 1 x m list
```

or simplify this

```
matrix = [ int(j) for j in input().split() ]
```

now suppose we have n rows, that means we have to do this n times which is simply looping n times ,

```
matrix = [ [ int(j) for j in input().split() ] for i in n ]
```

a more pythonic way is using map,

```
matrix= [ list( map(int, input().split() ) ) for i in range(n) ]
```